# (VBA) Fast Table Generation for Mathematics Journal Submission

Tags: algorithm, vba, excel

Am currently working my thesis around very famous math problem and need some help making a VBA form where I can just push enter and data of size (N) will be outputted.

I have made a full workbook using multi-dimensional index,match,rank, and indirect functions to then generate this data. This was more of a proof of concept showing the thought process behind the number pairs being utilized.

However, my 8 core processor has taken over 2 hours and is stuck at 60% generating a bell-curve shaped data array about 20 rows high, and 100 columns wide.

The data outputed can, fortunately, be "brute-force" generated by just using a generalized linear formula. Here is what I need it to look like:

```
                   TOP NUMBER: (2N/2) ROUNDED DOWN TO NEAREST ODD#
```

```
                                                               13  13
```

```
  {ODD#s} BETWEEN                                      11  11  11  11
```

```
  3 AND (2N/2) ROUNDED DOWN                    9   9   9   9   9   9
```

```
  TO NEAREST ODD#                      7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7
```

```
                               5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
```

```
                       3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
```

```
(2N|N>3)               6   8  10  12  14  16  18  20  22  22  24  26
```

Ideally I could have something like an external macro, who's dialogue opens and I input the Largest 2N I want, and excel generates a worksheet as above. The calculations would go something like this:

I type in 2N=26; 2N/4=6.5; 6.5 Rounded down to nearest whole number is 6. 6 is the number of rows going from (3 to 13). Add the 1 row of 26; 6+1=7.

There is great importance to this in my mathematics thesis. If you could help you may be a part of a nice discovery in number theory, and of course you'll have your "very uber excel-skills" recorded :D

I apologize if this is too much to ask. If it is, if you could kindly direct me I will figure it out myself. But it's not very typical to find a guide on how to populate your own data array's via user defined-formulas.

Below is an excel attachment of how it should look.

[NumberTheoryPairs.xls](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=17947172753794555439)

Comment: Interesting. I keep finding new applications for this procedure. Yes definitely related, but I'm doing Goldbach's Conjecture. But solving one should yield the other; at first glance given my work they seem to be interrelated. The idea here is to create a new methodology to approach number theory using remainders. I will share my final work here if there's enough interest before I submit for publishing as I am very pro-community collaboration.

Comment: As much as I like Excel (and have used it a lot over the years for math/statistics) something like this seems like it is better done in Python with its out-of-the box support for big integers.

Comment: Hi, this is probably not the best place to ask for this kind of help. Please email me at stefan@exceldevelopers.com and I'd be happy to help.

Comment: There is a disconnect between the pattern that you describe in the question and the pattern that the spreadsheet that you linked to displays. The one you have here is downright trivial. The one in the linked documnet seems much more obscure and appears to be cut-off on the right.

Comment: You are right there is a disconnect. It is related to the underlying generation of the data. I'm doing the following mapping: F--->F'-->Graph. In the OP I explained F'---->Graph but the F---->F' mapping has to do with a remainder Modulo function ranking. Would you like to see my original work?

Comment: @John Coleman    Here is the backend data so I clarify what is going on. http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=73993574401437195369    --sorry am having trouble with the mini-markdown formatting. And please make sure you open the xls file with only manual calculations on. Otherwise it may generate calculation errors as the formula is recursive

Comment: I apologize it seems my array formula in the first excel document did not follow through correctly. the entire 2nd row from the bottom should be 3's. I will post an updated one momentarily

Comment: Jason, what is your requirement that you are asking for? The post as shown here, or something else? How many rows are needed at max? 20?

Comment: @MacroMarc I basically need what is stated in the OP. I just need the bottom row to be defined as having a max. Say I want the bottom row to be all even numbers between 6-100 {6,8, 10, 12....100}, then the number of rows between the top right corner and the bottom right corner will be (100/4)+1; 26 rows high. And the number of columns will be (100-6)/2=47 columns wide. I need to just put in the largest 2N in the bottom row and have the data table generated as per the OP. I apologized if I may have confused you with the rest...it isn't pertinent to the request

Comment: @macromarc I hope that makes sense. Also remember the number of rows (height) will actually be 2N/4 rounded down to nearest whole number+1. I need a way to quickly generate these tables so I can test primality on sumwise and modulus pairs. This data table is a relation between common factors (multiplication) and subtraction pairs (addition)...so I can make a proof on Goldbach's by defining rules on each row, column, and diagonal's components. If you would like to chat on gmail chat I can hop on there right now. What's your email?

Comment: explain the pattern of whether there is 2 of the highest odd number etc. The example shows the odd numbers skipping two spots each upward row, How does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Excel Developer made a good point - normally StackOverflow frowns upon questions which ask to build a macro from scratch, but since I studied abstract algebra & Number Theory in Mathematics at university , I'd like to help out here :-)

The other point by John Coleman is that it's quite easy, but if you want to stick big integers in, Excel will run out of columns(but you can work with big arrays in memory)...

Play with this sub by fiddling with N, then if its what you want, then we can add a parameter to the function, and whip up a Userform to popup etc

```
Public Sub GoldbachTable()

  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells.Clear
  Dim N As Long
  N = 50

  Dim arr() As Variant
  Dim aRows As Long, aCols As Long
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, start As Long, oddNum
  start = 1
  oddNum = 3

  aRows = Round(N / 2 - 0.1) + 1
  aCols = N - 2
  ReDim arr(1 To aRows, 1 To aCols)

  For i = 1 To aCols
        arr(aRows, i) = (i + 2) * 2
  Next i

  For i = aRows - 1 To 1 Step -1
        For j = start To aCols
              arr(i, j) = oddNum
        Next j
        If start + 2 > aCols Then
              start = start + 1
        Else
              start = start + 2
        End If
        oddNum = oddNum + 2
  Next i

  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(aRows, aCols) = arr

End Sub
```